# Using Regexp,SUM and Having clause in more than one condition

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table as below:

Years | Job     | Skill | user_id

1       |  j1;j2 |    s1   |  1

2       |   j3      |    s2   |  1

1       |   j1      | s2;s3 |  1

3       |   j2       |    s1   |  1

When I do filtering,I wish to

`select user_id FROM Table WHERE`

`1. (Job regexp 'j1' AND TotalYears of Job REGEXP 'j1' >2),`

`2. (Skill regexp 's1' AND TotalYears of Skill regexp 's1' >3),`

so firstly I need to find out the total years of Job regexp 'j1' and also total years of Skill regexp 's1' first.

j1 = 2 years , s1 = 4 years

If I filter only Job regexp 'j1' , my query will be:

`SELECT Sum(Years) AS Years,Job AS Job FROM Table WHERE Job REGEXP 'j1' HAVING Years>2;`

but now I need to filter the Skill as well , how should I edit my query?

Thank you.

PS:I'm not sure whether my question title is correct , please correct me if it's not suitable with the content,thanks.

**EDIT (2013-07-10):**

My new table:

TotalWorkYear | JobScope                         | user_id

1 | Audit & Taxation;Banking/Financial;two | 1

4 | Publishing;Others;                                 | 1

0 | General/Cost Accounting;two                | 1

0 | evelen                                                   | 1

And here is my query: (I left join 2 tables,Members and Members7,which is not important)

`SELECT Members.user_id,SUM(IF(Members7.JobScope REGEXP 'eve',Members7.TotalWorkYear,0)) yearsJobScope,Members7.JobScope AS JobScope FROM Members LEFT JOIN Members7 ON Members.user_id=Members7.user_id GROUP BY user_id Having JobScope REGEXP 'eve' AND yearsJobScope >= 0`

Although there is one row regexp 'eve' and the totalworkyears is >= 0 , but it shows zero result,I think is caused by Group By user_id right,all records are group into one only according to user_id.Is there anyway to solve it?Thank you.

Comment: please include result you want to achieve in your question .

Comment: @Hiren Dhaduk Hi,my result should only show user_id that fulfill the 2 conditions.

Comment: I have added my ans . check it . is that you want ?

Comment: @Hiren Dhaduk Thank you so much,I checked it,please read my reply below your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT user_id,
         SUM(IF(job LIKE '%j1%',years,0)) yearsJob,
         SUM(IF(skill LIKE '%s1%', years,0)) yearsSkill
    FROM yourTable
GROUP BY user_id
  HAVING yearsJob>2
     AND yearsSkill>3;
```

Comment: Hi,sorry for disturbing,I;m facing another problem with my query,do you mind to help me?I edited my question.I really appreciate your help,thank you.

Comment: Sorry again,just now I tried `GROUP BY JobScope REGEXP 'eve',user_id` ,and it seems to works.Will keep trying and learning,sorry thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try Following query . it will work properly .

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT USERID
    FROM TABLE_3
    WHERE JOBS LIKE '%j1%'
    GROUP BY USERID 
    HAVING SUM(YEARS) > 0
) AS A
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT USERID
    FROM TABLE_3
    WHERE SKILL LIKE '%S1%'
    GROUP BY USERID 
    HAVING SUM(YEARS) > 0

) AS B ON A.USERID = B.USERID
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59cf5/1)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer,I tried it but it shows syntax error,starting from the INTERSECT.

Comment: Really thanks,though it will display 2 userid but it works.Thanks again.